# Spring Boot JdbcTemplate Filtering Mechanism

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've got a Spring Boot application with an API which retrieves entities from a data source. This is implemented using `JdbcTemplate` which for the most part is all I need.

However, I've got an endpoint which takes many query parameters which will need to be reflected in the database query. Something like

`GET /api/v1/people?age=10&height=125&weight=40&eyecolor=blue&...`

To save me spending the rest of my life creating the SQL query for this - does Spring provide some easy filtering mechanism? I'm aware that Spring JPA would do this but I'm hesitant to change all of my code to go down that route.

Comment: @J Smith : Hello , what approach did you end up taking with JDBCTemplate and applying many filters , as per user input , on your query . Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not offer a way to  Process/Make a Filter on 'many query parameters" however you may wanna look at GraphQL http://graphql.org

Comment: thanks for your reply - interesting idea using GraphQL, not something I've come across before but definitely worth consideration.